# Are these reasonable guesses for unattested verb forms? ἤρισσαν, θεωπρόπεεν

Tags: verbs, ancient-greek, homer

I'm making recordings of grammar drill exercises for the Homeric dialect ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSvneDSGXtc)). For verbs, there is a hassle because most verbs are not actually attested in very many forms. Typically I can look on wiktionary, which will show both attested forms and reasonable extrapolations to unattested ones. But sometimes I'm left uncertain. How about these two verbs?

[ἐρίζω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%87%CE%AF%CE%B6%CF%89) -> ἤρισσαν (by analogy with σχίζ; taking WP's unaugmented form listed as Epic, and adding the augment)

θεοπροπέω -> θεωπρόπεεν (treating it as a compound and augmenting the omicron to omega; uncontracted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the amount of irregularity and variation in Homeric verb forms, I actually think you'd be better off using the Attic forms for drills. But:

For ἐρίζω, Cunliffe's *Lexicon of the Homeric Dialect* lists the following attested aorist forms: ἐρίσωσι, ἐρίσειε, ἐρίσσειε, ἐρίσσειαν, ἐρίσαντε, ἐρίσαντες, ἐρίσσεται. (This isn't necessarily a complete list.) So apparently the sigma could be single or double as the meter required. I don't know if there are any augmented indicatives in Homer, but Hesiod (*Theogony* 928) has ἤρισα. So ἤρισσαν seems like a possible 3pl. aor. ind. act., but so would be ἤρισαν, ἔρισσαν, and ἔρισαν.

For θεοπροπέω: compounds of this type do not take the augment after the first member, but at the beginning. It's only verbs compounded with prepositions that have the "prefix-augment-verb" structure. So with the augment, the imperfect stem would be ἐθεοπροπε-. A possible 3sg. impf. act. ind. might be (ἐ)θεοπρόπεε(ν). (In this particular case contraction would actually be impossible in the Homeric poems as (ἐ)θεοπρόπει wouldn't scan.)

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful! It's indeed a challenge to cook up appropriate drills like this in the Homeric dialect, but that's the only dialect I'm currently working on. My previous experience is with modern Greek and a little koine -- in terms of interest, Attic would be a distant fourth for me.